# Making a table with numbered cells

Tags: tables

I would like to make a table with numbers at the top left corner of each cell. In particular, how do I make this table?

[image]

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477556/267280) almost does what I want, but I want to make the numbers left aligned and the main entry in the cell centered in each box.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should the small numbers be generated automatically or by hand? Please advise.

Comment: Preferably generated by hand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

By use of the `tabularray` package and separate narrow columns for numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
%\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!th]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, 
             colspec = {|X[1,l] | X[1,l] |  
                        *{3}{Q[r,h, font=\bfseries] X[2,c,m,mode=dmath] |}},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             rowsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m}
                 }
Elements of N 
    &   Elements of X
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Any $f$
            &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Injective $f$
                    &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Surjective $f$
                            &       \\
dist. 
    & dist. 
        &1. & x^n
                &2. & (x)_n
                        & 3. & x!S(n.x)         
                                \\ 
indist.
    & dist.
        &4. & \left(\binom{x}{n}\right)
                &5. & \binom{x}{n}
                        & 6. & \left(\binom{x}{n-x}\right)  
                                \\
dist.
    & indist.
        &7. & \begin{multlined}
                S(n,0) + S(n,1)\\
                   +\dots + S(n,x)
              \end{multlined}   
                &8. & \begin{aligned}
                        1 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n\leqslant x   \\
                        0 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n > x
                      \end{aligned}
                        & 9. & S(n,x)
                                \\
indist.
    & indist.
        &10.& \begin{multlined}
                p_0(n) + p_1(n)\\
                   +\dots + p_x(x)
              \end{multlined}
                &11.& \begin{aligned}
                        1 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n\leqslant x   \\
                        0 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n > x
                      \end{aligned}
                        &12. & p_x(n)
                                \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
A possible wee bit different table design where first two column are narrower and other (with math expressions) wider:

[image]

For it the following changes in `tblr` preamble and column headers are done:

```
% document preamble
% ...
\begin{tblr}{hlines, 
             colspec = {| l | l |   % <---
                        *{3}{Q[r,h, font=\bfseries] X[c,m,mode=dmath] |},% <---
             colsep  = 3pt,
             rowsep  = 4pt,
             row{1,2}= {font=\small\bfseries, c, m, rowsep=1pt}     % <---
                 }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    Elements of:    % <--- new
    &   & \SetCell[c=2, r=2]{c}  Any $f$    % <---
            &   & \SetCell[c=2,r=2]{c}  Injective $f$   % <---
                    &   & \SetCell[c=2,r=2]{c}  Surjective $f$  % <---
                            &       \\
X   & Y &   &   &   &   &   &       \\  % <--- new
%% table body
```

Comment: @F. Pantigny, thank you for edit!

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can can put the numbers in the cells after the construction of the main tabular with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!th]
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccX[c]X[c]X[c]}[width=\linewidth,hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\RowStyle[bold,cell-space-limits=5pt]{}
\Block{}{Elements\\ of N} 
    & \Block{}{Elements\\ of X}
        & Any $f$
            & Injective $f$
                & Surjective $f$ \\
dist. 
    & dist. 
        & $x^n$
            & $(x)_n$
                & $x!S(n,x)$ \\ 
indist.
    & dist.
        & $\left(\binom{x}{n}\right)$
            & $\binom{x}{n}$
                & $\left(\binom{x}{n-x}\right)$ \\
dist.
    & indist.
         & $\begin{aligned}
             S(n,0) + S(n,1)\\
                +\dots + S(n,x)
           \end{aligned}$   
             & $\begin{aligned}
                 1 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n\leqslant x   \\
                 0 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n > x
               \end{aligned}$
                 & $S(n,x)$ \\
indist.
    & indist.
        & $\begin{aligned}
            p_0(n) + p_1(n)\\
               +\dots + p_x(x)
          \end{aligned}$
            & $\begin{aligned}
                1 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n\leqslant x   \\
                0 & \quad \mathrm{if}\ n > x
              \end{aligned}$
                & $p_x(n)$ \\
\CodeAfter
  \newcounter{cell}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {2,3,4,5} 
       \foreach \j in {3,4,5}
          { 
            \stepcounter{cell}
            \node [below right] at (\i-|\j) { \bfseries \small \thecell } ; 
          } ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`.

[image: Output of the above code]